# How do I recognize command-line parameters in my Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, command-line, parameters

I plan to run specific application commands every X days using Task Scheduler. Do I have to write support for command-line parameters first, so Scheduler can execute it?

If so, does anyone know any good command-parameter components?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to read any cmd line parameters that were passed to your application at start-up you can use Delphi's inbuild functions.

```
ParamCount   // Number of cmd params passed at startup
ParamStr(0) // string of param zero
```

So calling you program like so

```
c:\myapp.exe -foo -bar
```

would give the following result

```
ParamStr(0) = c:\myapp.exe
ParamStr(1) = -foo
ParamStr(2) = -bar
```

Answer (score 23):

You may wish to consider the **FindCmdLineSwitch** from the **SysUtils** unit.

```
function FindCmdLineSwitch(const SwitchValue:string):Boolean;
function FindCmdLineSwitch(const SwitchValue:string; IgnoreCase:Boolean):Boolean;
function FindCmdLineSwitch(const SwitchValue:string; SwitchChars:TSysCharSet; IgnoreCase:Boolean):Boolean;
```

This allows to check for the presence of a command line switch, specify whether to ignore its case and optionally use different switch characters e.g. '-' or '/'